# A Keras model trains well, but predicts the same value

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mobilenet

Let's try to make `MobileNet V. 2` locate a bright band on a noisy image. Yes, it is overkill to use a deep convolutional network for such a tack, but originally it was intended just like a smoke test to make sure the model works. We will train it on synthetic data:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

SHAPE = (32, 320, 1)
def gen_sample():
    while True:
        data = np.random.normal(0, 1, SHAPE)
        i = np.random.randint(0, SHAPE[1]-8)
        data[:,i:i+8,:] += 4
        yield data.astype(np.float32), np.float32(i)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen_sample, output_signature=(
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=SHAPE, dtype=tf.float32),
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32))).batch(100)

d, i = next(gen_sample())
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(d)
plt.show()
```

[image: A sample image]

Now we build and train a model:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(
        input_shape=SHAPE, include_top=False, weights=None, alpha=0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
        learning_rate=tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
            initial_learning_rate=0.01, decay_steps=1000, decay_rate=0.9)),
    loss='mean_squared_error')
history = model.fit(ds, steps_per_epoch=10, epochs=40)
```

We use generated data, so we don't need a validation set, do we? So we can just watch how the loss decreases. And it does decrease decently well:

```
Epoch 1/40
10/10 [==============================] - 27s 2s/step - loss: 15054.8417
Epoch 2/40
10/10 [==============================] - 23s 2s/step - loss: 193.9126
Epoch 3/40
10/10 [==============================] - 24s 2s/step - loss: 76.9586
Epoch 4/40
10/10 [==============================] - 25s 2s/step - loss: 68.8521
...
Epoch 37/40
10/10 [==============================] - 20s 2s/step - loss: 4.5258
Epoch 38/40
10/10 [==============================] - 20s 2s/step - loss: 22.1212
Epoch 39/40
10/10 [==============================] - 20s 2s/step - loss: 28.4854
Epoch 40/40
10/10 [==============================] - 20s 2s/step - loss: 18.0123
```

Training happened to stop not at the best result, but it still should be reasonable: the answers should be around the true value ±8. Let's test it:

```
d, i = list(ds.take(1))[0]
model.evaluate(d, i)
np.stack((model.predict(d).ravel(), i.numpy()), 1)[:10,]
```

```
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 16955.7871
array([[ 66.84666 , 222.      ],
       [ 66.846664,  46.      ],
       [ 66.846664,  71.      ],
       [ 66.84668 , 268.      ],
       [ 66.846664,  86.      ],
       [ 66.84668 , 121.      ],
       [ 66.846664, 301.      ],
       [ 66.84667 , 106.      ],
       [ 66.84665 , 138.      ],
       [ 66.84667 ,  95.      ]], dtype=float32)
```

Wow! Where does this huge evaluation loss come from? And why the model keeps predicting the same stupid value? Everything was so good during the training!

Actually, in a day or so I realized what was going on, but I offer to others a possibility to solve this charade and earn some points.

Comment: If you realize the problem and know the solution, why don't you just answer your own question!!

Comment: I explained it in the last sentence. If no one gives the right answer in a few days, I give my own.

Comment: I got the network to work by replacing the mobilenet backbone with a simple conv layer with 32 filters. But I can't think of a reason why it did not work with the mobilenet backbone. Bigger the network the more capability it has to learn the data. I am guessing overfitting here is fine since the validation set is the same training. But it looks like it is getting in some kind of local minimum. But I can't think a good enough reason to explain the behavior. What was the issue with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that a network reasonably functioning in the training mode failed to work in the inference mode. What might be the cause? There are basically two layer types working differently in the two modes: dropout and batch normalization. In `MobileNet V. 2`, we have only batch normalization, so let's consider how it works.

In the training mode a BN layer calculates batch mean and variance and normalizes the data using these batch values. At the same time it remembers the mean and variance as a moving average weighted with a coefficient called `momentum`.

```
moving_mean = moving_mean * momentum + mean(batch) * (1 - momentum)
moving_var = moving_var * momentum + var(batch) * (1 - momentum)
```

Indeed, this `momentum` is an important hyperparameter, especially if true batch statistics are far from the initial values. Suppose the initial variance value is `1.0`, the momentum is `0.99` (which is the default), and the true data variance is `0.1`. Than the 10% error (`var < 0.11`) can be achieved after 447 batches.

Now the root cause of the problem: in `MobileNet` all the numerous BN layers have `momentum=0.999`, which means it will take 4497 batch steps to achieve the same 10% error! When you are training on a very large heterogeneous data set like ImageNet in small batches, this is a 100% reasonable hyperparameter choice. But in this toy example the result is that the BN layers just fail to remember true data statistics during 400 batches and use completely wrong values during inference!

And the fix is very simple: just change the momenta before `model.compile`:

```
for layer in model.layers[0].layers:
    if type(layer) is tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization:
        layer.momentum = 0.9
```