# Keras model returns high validation accuracy while training, but accuracy is very low while evaluating

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mobilenet

I am trying to train a simple `MobileNetV3Small` under `keras.applications` as shown below

```
base_model = keras.applications.MobileNetV3Small(
        input_shape= INPUT_SHAPE,
        alpha=.125,
        include_top=False,
        classes=1,
        dropout_rate = 0.2,
        weights=None)

    x = keras.layers.Flatten()(base_model.output)
    preds = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
    model = keras.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=preds)

 model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
                optimizer='RMSprop',
                metrics=["binary_accuracy"])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1.0 / 255,
        rotation_range=40,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        vertical_flip=True,
    )

    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        os.path.join(DATA_ROOT, 'train'),
        target_size=(56,56),
        batch_size=128,
        class_mode="binary",
    )


    validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0 / 255)
    validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        os.path.join(DATA_ROOT, 'val'),
        target_size=(56,56),
        batch_size=128,
        class_mode="binary",
    )

    model_checkpoint_callback = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath=SAVE_DIR,
        save_weights_only=True,
        monitor='val_binary_accuracy',
        mode='max',
        save_best_only=True)

    es_callback = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10)

    model.fit(train_generator,
                epochs=100,
                validation_data=validation_generator,
                callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback, es_callback],
                shuffle=True)
```

When I train the model I got validation accuracy around 0.94. But when I call `model.evaluate` on the exact same validation data, the accuracy becomes 0.48. When I call `model.predict` with any data it outputs constant value 0.51...

There is nothing wrong with learning rate, optimizer or metrics. What could be wrong here?

---

**EDIT:**

After training when I run

```
pred_results = model.evaluate(validation_generator)
print(pred_results)
```

it gives me the output for 1 epoch trained network:

> 6/6 [==============================] - 1s 100ms/step - loss: 0.6935 -
> binary_accuracy: 0.8461

However, when I save and load the model with either `model.save()` or `tf.keras.models.save_model()`. The output becomes something like this:

> 6/6 [==============================] - 2s 100ms/step - loss: 0.6935 -
> binary_accuracy: 0.5028 [0.6935192346572876, 0.5027709603309631]

and output of the `model.predict(validation_generator)` is:

> [[0.5080832]  [0.5080832]  [0.5080832]  [0.5080832]
> .
> .
> .  [0.5080832]  [0.5080832]]

---

**What I've tried so far:**

1. Used `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory()` instead of `ImageDataGenerator`
2. Fixed tensorflow and numpy seeds globally.
3. Found similar problem in another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67502042/a-keras-model-trains-well-but-predicts-the-same-value), and decreased `momentum` parameter of MobileNet BatchNormalization layers one by one.

```
for layer in model.layers[0].layers:
    if type(layer) is tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization:
        layer.momentum = 0.9
```

First two moves do not have an effect, the after applying the third step, I get no longer same predictions for any input. However, `evaluate()` and `predict()` still have different accuracy values.

Comment: What is the value of `NUM_CLASSES`?

Comment: It is 1. I edited it in the post now.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem with my own data, but I get low accuracy on the validation set during training.

Comment: Which dataset have you tried?

Comment: You need to load MobileNet with trained weights, i.e. set `weights= 'imagenet'`.

Comment: But I cannot do it with very small alpha values, which accepts either 0.75 or 1.0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245951/discussion-between-elbe-and-bhoke).

Comment: Some people believe that, after loading the model, that's better to compile the model again. Can you please do it and tell us the result?

Comment: @MojtabaAbdiKh. already tried it, but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting `shuffle = False` in `validation_datagen.flow_from_directory()`? It's a little misleading but the `.flow_from_directory()` method shuffles by default, which is problematic when generating your validation dataset. This is shuffling your validation data when you try to call `.predict`. Whereas in your training loop, the `.fit` method implicitly DOESN'T shuffle the validation set.

The reason I think this is the issue, is because you state that calling `.predict()` on the validation set nets you ~.5 accuracy, and you're also running a binary classification (sigmoid output with binary cross entropy loss), which makes perfect sense IF you're (mistakenly) shuffling your validation data. Untrained binary classifiers on balanced datasets will usually do around 50% accuracy (.5 for 0, .5 for 1) since it's just guessing at that point.

**Source**: I've built and trained a lot of image classification models before, and this happened to me a lot.

Comment: After I decreased momentum parameter, model starts to give different output. Please also see my comment under Mercury's answer. I am suspicious about shuffling too. However, I do not understand why shuffling affects when you import whole validation dataset?

Comment: @Bhoke You're correct, in principle it shouldn't matter, but I think it matters here because you didn't set the seed argument in `validation_datagen.flow_from_directory()`. If I recall correctly, it will shuffle everytime you call the data unless you set the seed directly in that method. I know you specified that you set the seed in tensorflow and numpy globally, but I think you need to directly set the seed in this method because it's keras-specific. So try either setting `shuffle=False`, or leave it alone and set `seed=` some integer.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth trying `model.save_weights('directory')` and then rebuilding your model (i think here that is re-running the `base_model = ...` code) through `model.load_weights('directory')`. That is what i do in my own models, and when i then do that, the accuracy/loss stay the exact same before and after saving and loading.

Comment: Already tried it. Maybe I should re-edit question to mention it.

Comment: Have you tried checking the weights are the same pre and post save? as in `if model.get_weights() == open("directory","r") print("same")`? And when you load the model, do you always get the same accuracy? E.g load it one time and get 0.5123, then delete the model, load it again, and the accuracy is the same. Because if not then it would seem like the training set is changing, or the weights are not in fact being loaded.

Comment: Yes also checked it, there is no problem with weights. Decreasing `momentum` parameter of MobileNet seems to solve predict issue (I guess model could not learn with high momentum or it yield to dying ReLU problem). I think a fixed seed is also going to solve `evaluate()` and `predict()` inconsistency.

Comment: Seems like it would be the seed then, hope that that will solve it!

Answer (score 0):

If you run `pred_results = model.evaluate(validation_generator)`
after you fit the model, the loaded weights at this moment are the ones updated on last training epoch.
What you have to do is after `model.fit` is loading the weights saved from
`model_checkpoint_callback` with something like

```
model = model.load_weights(SAVE_DIR)` # and then .evaluate
pred_results = model.evaluate(validation_generator)
print(pred_results)
```